# Graph of inequality

Tags: plotting

```
$Assumptions = z > 0
$Assumptions = x > 0
$Assumptions = y >0

ineq = 0.5[0.5 Abs[x/(1 + x) - y/(1 + y)]+ Abs[Log[1 + y] - Log[1 + z]]] <= 0.5 [Abs[x - y]+Abs[y - z]];

Plot3D[Evaluate[List @@ ineq], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", ClippingStyle -> None,  AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

Mathematica throw error
Kindly help me.

Comment: Maybe you meant to define `ineq` as follows? `ineq = 0.5 (0.5 Abs[x/(1 + x) - y/(1 + y)] + 
      Abs[Log[1 + y] - Log[1 + z]]) <= 0.5 (Abs[x - y] + Abs[y - z]);` (_Mathematica_ distiguishes between parentheses `()` and brackets `[]`.)

Comment: I wonder if there is something in the docs for `Plot3D` that suggests it can plot inequalities?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your inequality is true everywhere in the specified region:

```
ineq = 0.5 (0.5 Abs[x/(1 + x) - y/(1 + y)] + 
      Abs[Log[1 + y] - Log[1 + z]]) <= 0.5 (Abs[x - y] + Abs[y - z]);
RegionPlot3D[ineq, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic]
```

[image]